# How to implement a "either nested type or void" trait?

Tags: c++, inner-classes, sfinae, type-traits

I'm working with some classes that may have a nested type defined. Whenever this nested type is not defined I pretend like this nested type is `void`. For example, here is the code that should work:

```cpp
struct HasNestedTypeDefined {
    using Nested = int;
};

struct VoidNestedTypeDefined {
    using Nested = void;
};

struct NoNestedTypeDefined {
};

static_assert(!std::is_same_v<reveal_nested_type< HasNestedTypeDefined>::type, void>);
static_assert( std::is_same_v<reveal_nested_type< HasNestedTypeDefined>::type, int>);
static_assert( std::is_same_v<reveal_nested_type<VoidNestedTypeDefined>::type, void>);
static_assert(!std::is_same_v<reveal_nested_type<VoidNestedTypeDefined>::type, int>);
static_assert( std::is_same_v<reveal_nested_type<  NoNestedTypeDefined>::type, void>);
static_assert(!std::is_same_v<reveal_nested_type<  NoNestedTypeDefined>::type, int>);
```

So far I've got this working:

```cpp
template<typename T, typename R = void>  
struct enable_if_type {
    using type = R;
};

template<typename T, typename = void>
struct reveal_nested_type {
    using type = void;
};

template<typename T>
struct reveal_nested_type<T, typename enable_if_type<typename T::Nested>::type> {
    using type = typename T::Nested;
};
```

I thought that SFINAE should work even without using `enable_if_type`, like that:

```cpp
template<typename T, typename = void>
struct reveal_nested_type {
    using type = void;
};

template<typename T>
struct reveal_nested_type<T, typename T::Nested> {
    using type = typename T::Nested;
};
```

but the partial specialization is never used in this case, even if the `typename T::Nested` is defined. Why does SFINAE ignore it? The follow up question: is there a more idiomatic way to implement the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note your last attempt

```
template<typename T, typename = void>
struct reveal_nested_type {
    using type = void;
};

template<typename T>
struct reveal_nested_type<T, typename T::Nested> {
    using type = typename T::Nested;
};
```

actually does work for `reveal_nested_type<VoidNestedTypeDefined>`. What's happening is that because of the default template argument on the primary `reveal_nested_type` class template, `reveal_nested_type<T>` means the same as `reveal_nested_type<T, void>`. So the partial specialization `reveal_nested_type<T, typename T::Nested>` will only match if the nested type exists *and* the nested type is identical to `void`.

Here [`std::void_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/void_t) is a nice way to fix this:

```
template<typename T, typename = void>
struct reveal_nested_type {
    using type = void;
};

template<typename T>
struct reveal_nested_type<T, std::void_t<typename T::Nested>> {
    using type = typename T::Nested;
};
```

This is a typical use of `void_t`, just using SFINAE to require that a dependent type is valid, and/or that a dependent expression is valid (via the dependent type `decltype(expr)`), but ignoring what that type actually is.

The above is essentialy what I'd probably use for C++03 to C++17. But if you can use C++20 constraints, another way would be:

```
template <typename T>
struct reveal_nested_type {
    using type = void;
};

template <typename T> requires requires { typename T::Nested; }
struct reveal_nested_type<T> {
    using type = typename T::Nested;
};
```

(Yes, two `requires` keywords. The first introduces a constraint on the template which expects a Boolean expression, and the second introduces a requires-expression which gives a Boolean expression from a list of requirements.)

Comment: @DavidStone Thanks for the correction. I should know to copy/paste the tested version even for something that short.